# Can we subset on an attribute more than once in a decision tree?

Tags: decision-tree

Would splitting on an attribute more than once while building a decision tree be considered a case of over fitting ? I remember my professor telling me that while building a tree choose attributes with higher information gain as higher level nodes. Would that eliminate the possibility of choosing an attribute more than once ??

Comment: No.I had this doubt while reading the material abt decision trees

Comment: What does *splitting on an attribute* mean? what language are you using?

Comment: It depends on the algorithm you are using. If your algorithm check for statistical significance using, say, Bonferroni test in each split, than you shouldn't overfit